# Interface not resolving for parameter type

Tags: c#

**I have the following classes:**

```
namespace CommonInterfaces
{
    public interface INode
    {
        int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
        int? ChildNodeId { get; set; }
    }
}

public class FieldDependencyModel : DataModel<int>, ICacheable
{

    #region Field

    private int _FieldDependencyId;
    private int? _FieldId;
    private int? _FieldParentId;

    #endregion  

    #region Properties

    public virtual int FieldDependencyId
    {
        get { return getPropertyValue("FieldDependencyId",_FieldDependencyId); }
        set { _FieldDependencyId = value; }
    }

    public virtual int? ChildNodeId
    {
        get { return getPropertyValue("FieldId",_FieldId); }
        set { _FieldId = value; }
    }

    public virtual int? ParentNodeId
    {
        get { return getPropertyValue("FieldParentId",_FieldParentId); }
        set { _FieldParentId = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}


    public interface IFieldDependencyService
    {
        IList<FieldDependency> GetAllFieldDependencies();
    }

    public class FieldDependency : FieldDependencyModel, INode
    {
    }


    public class FieldDependencyDataService : BaseDataService, IFieldDependencyService
    {
        public FieldDependencyDataService(DataAccessHandle serviceHandler) : base(serviceHandler) {}

        public IList<FieldDependency> GetAllFieldDependencies()
        {
            return _accessService.loadAll<FieldDependency>();
        }
    }

    public class TreeService
    {
        private IList<INode> _relationships;
        private INode _rootNode;    


        public TreeService(INode rootNode, IList<INode> nodeRelationships)
        {
            _relationships = nodeRelationships;
            _rootNode = rootNode;
        }


        public Tree<INode> BuildTree()
        {
            Tree<INode> tree;

            tree = new Tree<INode>(_rootNode, _relationships);

            return tree;
        }
    }
```

I try sending in a type which impliments **INode** and it still says the following error when I try passing in the fieldDependencies to the new TreeService instantiation:

```
Error   5   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<FieldDependency>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<CommonInterfaces.INode>'
```

**Here's my calling code where I get this error:**

```
            IList<FieldDependency> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies();

            FieldDependency rootDependency = fieldDependencies.First(d => d.ParentNodeId == null);
 var service = new TreeService(rootDependency, fieldDependencies); // fails here, doesn't like fieldDependencies
```

Comment: How are `INode` and `FieldDependency` related?

Comment: updated, see above, posted more of the backend.

Comment: Try not to bold your text in the future, it makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because you're trying to convert an `IList<FieldDependency>` to an `IList<INode>`, so the actual object you're trying to convert is the `IList` that have the related types as their generic types. There are a few courses of action you can take to get around this.

### Replace `IList<FieldDependency>` with `IList<INode>`

You could change your code so that the `IList<FieldDependency>` is an `IList<INode>`.

```
public interface IDataFieldDependencyService
{
    IList<INode> GetAllFieldDependencies();
}

public class FieldDependencyDataService : BaseDataService, IFieldDependencyService
{
    public FieldDependencyDataService(DataAccessHandle serviceHandler) : base(serviceHandler) {}

    public IList<INode> GetAllFieldDependencies()
    {
        return _accessService.loadAll<FieldDependency>();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
IList<INode> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies();

INode rootDependency = fieldDependencies.First(d => d.ParentNodeId == null);
var service = new TreeService(rootDependency, fieldDependencies);
```

---

### `Select` and cast as `INode`

You could also select all the elements from `_service.GetAllFieldDependencies()` and box them in `INode`.

```
IList<INode> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies()
    .Select(e => (INode)e)
    .ToList();

INode rootDependency = fieldDependencies.First(d => d.ParentNodeId == null);
var service = new TreeService(rootDependency, fieldDependencies);
```

### Covariance

If you work with `IEnumerable`s then you can probably do what you want [using covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) (.NET 4 I believe).

```
public class TreeService
{
    private IEnumerable<INode> _relationships;
    private INode _rootNode;    


    public TreeService(INode rootNode, IEnumerable<INode> nodeRelationships)
    {
        _relationships = nodeRelationships;
        _rootNode = rootNode;
    }


    public Tree<INode> BuildTree()
    {
        Tree<INode> tree;

        tree = new Tree<INode>(_rootNode, _relationships);

        return tree;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
IEnumerable<INode> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies();

INode rootDependency = fieldDependencies.First(d => d.ParentNodeId == null);
var service = new TreeService(rootDependency, fieldDependencies);
```

Comment: Ok I guess I don't understand why if the main POCO has it implementing INode: public class FieldDependency : FieldDependencyModel, INode

Comment: the thing is also, I can't, because I don't ant my GetAll returning INode as it's getting classes from my NHibernate model and those do NOT implement INode and shouldn't.  I put INode on my POCO intermediate class public class FieldDependency : FieldDependencyModel, INode becuase higher up I need to make sure whatever DTO is passed up implements INode.

Comment: the return _accessService.loadAll<FieldDependency>(); is returning NHibernate models and won't have any INode implemented, that INode is a custom Inteface I created for the purpose upstream, not here.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand.  Because if FieldDependency implements INode, it should be fine...I should be able to reference it by IList<FieldDependency> and send that in for IList<INode> to my tree.  Why would I have to cast if the whole point is that I added that INode down lower so that when I got the POCO back it'd have already implemented INode and so I could interchange INode for FieldDependency, either or should work when passing it in?  I mean casting is bad...for performance but just want to understand what I am not getting here.  I've used interfaces & have not seen this before.

Comment: thanks for the update, I'm still just like what the heck?  Well I do not have an option to convert that CRUD to an IList<INode> as like I said the service brings me back an NHibernate model which represents the database fields of x table.  The CRUD ultimately passes back a POCO, not the model as you can see which implements INode...or should I say I have an intermediate class which is inheriting the POCO and also implements INode so the POCO must satisfy that interface.

Comment: I suggest reading about covariance and contravariance to help you understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: yea I guess I'll need to  :)

Comment: thanks much!  IEnumerable seems to work ...Unit testing it now so we'll see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IList<INode> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies()
.First(d => d.ParentNodeId == null).Select(d => (INode)d);
```

Comment: again why shouldn't I be able to do IList<FieldDepenency>, it should be ok as it implements INode, through obviously polymorphism it should not care?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined field dependencies as a list of FieldDependency, i.e.

```
fieldDependencies.GetType() == typeof<IList<FieldDependency>>
```

the TreeService constructor's 2nd parameter expects `tyepof(IList<INode>>)`

you should be able to just change the way you define the variable fieldDependencies as `IList<INode>`

i.e.

`IList<INode> fieldDependencies = _service.GetAllFieldDependencies()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var service = new TreeService(rootDependency, fieldDependencies.Cast<INode>().ToList());
```

Having class B derived from class A does not guarantee that you will be able to cast object generic collection type with type parameter B to generic collection type with type parameter A.

You can read more about contravariance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).